# resampling of 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 2D array of size `(3,2)` and i have to re sample this by using nearest neighbor, linear and bi cubic method of interpolation so that the size become `(4,3)`.

I am using *Python*, `numpy` and `scipy` for this.

How can I achieve resampling of the input array?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by resampling? Do you have a link to an explaination of what that means?

Comment: actually, i need to convert a low resolution image to high resolution but using numpy.

Comment: I don't think that is possible unless you have a better resolution original image. Once you have taken an image, there is no sub-pixel information in that image...

Comment: I have one Panchromatic Image( High Resolution) and one multispectral image(low resolution). and i have to change this low resolution to High Resolution.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good tutorial on re-sampling using convolution [here](https://clouard.users.greyc.fr/Pantheon/experiments/rescaling/index-en.html).

For integer factor up-scaling:

```
import numpy
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage, signal

# Scale factor
factor = 2

# Input image
a = numpy.arange(16).reshape((4,4))

# Empty image enlarged by scale factor
b = numpy.zeros((a.shape[0]*factor, a.shape[0]*factor))

# Fill the new array with the original values
b[::factor,::factor] = a

# Define the convolution kernel
kernel_1d = scipy.signal.boxcar(factor)
kernel_2d = numpy.outer(kernel_1d, kernel_1d)

# Apply the kernel by convolution, seperately in each axis
c = scipy.signal.convolve(b, kernel_2d, mode="valid")
```

Note that the factor can be different for each axis, and that you can also apply the convolution sequentially, on each axis. The kernels for bi-linear and bi-cubic are also shown in the link, with the bilinear interpolation making use of a triangular signal (`scipy.signal.triang`) and bi-cubic being a piece wise function.

You should also mind which portion of the interpolated image is valid; along the edges there is not sufficient support for the kernel.

Bi-cubic interpolation is the best option of the three, as far as satellite imagery goes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution for this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html.

Nearest neighbor interpolation is order=0, bilinear interpolation is order=1, and bicubic is order=3 (default).

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

x = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2).astype(float)
z = (4/3, 3/2)
print('Original array:\n{0}\n\n'.format(x))
methods=['nearest-neighbor', 'bilinear', 'biquadratic', 'bicubic']
for o in range(4):
    print('Resampled with {0} interpolation:\n {1}\n\n'.
    format(methods[o],  scipy.ndimage.zoom(x, z, order=o)))
```

This results to:

```
Original array:
[[0. 1.]
 [2. 3.]
 [4. 5.]]


Resampled with nearest-neighbor interpolation:
 [[0. 1. 1.]
 [2. 3. 3.]
 [2. 3. 3.]
 [4. 5. 5.]]


Resampled with bilinear interpolation:
 [[0.         0.5        1.        ]
 [1.33333333 1.83333333 2.33333333]
 [2.66666667 3.16666667 3.66666667]
 [4.         4.5        5.        ]]


Resampled with biquadratic interpolation:
 [[1.04083409e-16 5.00000000e-01 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.11111111e+00 1.61111111e+00 2.11111111e+00]
 [2.88888889e+00 3.38888889e+00 3.88888889e+00]
 [4.00000000e+00 4.50000000e+00 5.00000000e+00]]


Resampled with bicubic interpolation:
 [[5.55111512e-16 5.00000000e-01 1.00000000e+00]
 [1.03703704e+00 1.53703704e+00 2.03703704e+00]
 [2.96296296e+00 3.46296296e+00 3.96296296e+00]
 [4.00000000e+00 4.50000000e+00 5.00000000e+00]]
```